# How to include bash scripts with relative path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 3 scripts:

Script A:

```
echo "Hey you!"
```

Script B:

```
source ./A.sh
```

Script C:

```
source ./libs/B.sh
```

So scripts A and B in folder "libs" and script C use script B from this directory.

Script C throw Error:

> ./libs/B.sh: line 1: ./A.sh: No such file or directory

**How to correct use script "including" in this case?**

*I understand why this error occurs, but I do not understand how to fix it.
Also! I do not want to include with full path as / home /.../libs/A.sh etc.
I want to create move-free scripts without permanent editing.*

Comment: Remove `./` from the beginning. `. <scriptname>` and `source <scriptname>` are same thing. As you mentioned script A and B is in libs directory and I am assuming script C is also in the same directory you don't need to use `./` if all three scripts reside in the same directory.

Comment: @GauravPathak if `scriptname` is found in `$PATH`, that file will be used instead of the one in the current directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify the directory of the script itself. By default a single dot means "current **working directory**".

Script B, modified version:

```
source "$(dirname "$0")/A.sh"
```

Same mod recommended for C:

```
source "$(dirname "$0")/libs/B.sh"
```

You can alternatively use `${0##*/}` for the same effect as `$(dirname "$0")`

Or, to make sure it's the full path to the script, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`:

Script B, modified:

```
source "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")/A.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you! Also this: 
> source "$(dirname "$0")/libs/B.sh" 
Doesn't work.
But this: 
> source "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")/A.sh" 
Worked correct.

Comment: What if you have `../B.sh` rather than `./libs/B.sh`?

Comment: @Erwann The system will resolve it for you, so go ahead and use `$(dirname "$0")/../B.sh`.